# Shortcode en página estatica de un Theme propio usando plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Algunas aclaraciones para empezar.

He creado un theme propio, y fui creando varios plugins para custom posts de mi sitio wordpress.

Dentro de uno de mis plugins necesito usar shortcodes y funciuonan correctamente si los agrego dentro de posts generados desde el cms de wordpress.

Ahora bien, tengo una página estática en mi theme que dentro tiene un formulario de contacto, en la cual quiero agregar un shortcode para que la vista del formulario de contacto no esté agregada en el php sino en mi plugin.

Al usar el shortcode dentro de la página estática no lo imprime, sin embargo si dicho shortcode lo ingreso dentro de un post si lo imprime correctamente.

Pregunta:
Cual sería la forma de utilizar un shortcode en una página creada por mí y no como una entrada de wordpress?

mi página: "page-contacto.php"

El código:

```
<?php /*  * Template Name: Contacto  */   // Exit if accessed directly
 defined('ABSPATH') or die('No script kiddies please!'); ?>   <?php
 get_header(); ?>   <div class="container">   <?php if (have_posts()) :
     while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

       [ps_contact_form_print_view]<br>
     <?php endwhile;
     endif; ?> </div>   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Parate de mi plugin:

```
<?php function ps_contact_form_print_view_shortcode() {
     return 'imprime todo el formulario'; } add_shortcode('ps_contact_form_print_view',
 'ps_contact_form_print_view_shortcode'); ?>
```

Aclaración:
Si el shortcode lo uso dentro de un post generado desde el cms de wordpress funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tan sencillo como usar la funcion de callback y ejecutarla directamente.

```
<?php echo ps_contact_form_print_view_shortcode();?>
```

Existe una funcion de Wordpress para ejecutar los shortcodes dentro de PHP, pero es menos recomendable que llamar la funcion directamente como hicimos arriba. De todas formas te la dejo por si la llegas a necesitar

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[ps_contact_form_print_view]' ); ?>
```